# Building an Expression Tree using prefix notation

Tags: c++, expression-trees

I'm working on a project using C++ to build an expression tree. I am having trouble building the tree because I believe I incorrectly increment my input string at some point. My two functions in question are as follows:

```
template <typename DataType>
void ExprTree<DataType>::build()
{
    char *input = new char[20];
    cin >> input;
    buildHelper(root, input);
}
```

The above function takes a string from the user as input, in prefix notation, and passes it to a recursive builder function to assist in building the tree.

```
template <typename DataType>
void ExprTree<DataType>::buildHelper(ExprTreeNode *&node, char *input)
{
    if (*input != NULL)
    {
        node = new ExprTreeNode(*input, NULL, NULL);
        if ((*input) == '*' || (*input) == '+' || (*input) == '-' || (*input) == '/')
        {
            input++;
            buildHelper(node->left, input);
            input++;
            buildHelper(node->right, input);
        }
    }
}
```

The above function takes the string from the previous function and attempts to build the tree.

I am using the following string as a test case: *+13-64

The tree that I build looks like this:

```
      1

*<
              3
      +<
              1
```

I believe I am having issues incrementing the input from the user correctly, but I can't be sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Edit:

I have included the ExprTreeNode function as well:

```
template <typename DataType>
ExprTree<DataType>::ExprTreeNode::ExprTreeNode(char elem, ExprTreeNode *leftPtr, ExprTreeNode *rightPtr)
{
    dataItem = elem;
    left = leftPtr;
    right = rightPtr;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any code to parse the numbers. Can your `ExpTreeNode` hold a number also? You need the `ExpTreeNode` to hold numbers. You can accomplish that by sub-classing `ExpTreeNode` to `NumberNode` and `OperatorNode`. You can also use another method to differentiate between the two types of nodes.

Comment: Yes, my ExprTreeNode holds a character, which the string is read in as. 1, 3, 6, and 4 are all characters in the string.